# setTimeout function leaks memory in Chromium

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, settimeout

I have got a fairly simple function for a live clock on a website used as a dashboard (i.e. the site should be able to run for weeks without refresh).

My code:

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
  getTime(); //Get the initial time.
});

var time;

function getTime() {
  time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true, timeZone: 'America/Puerto_Rico' });

  $("#clock").html(time);

  setTimeout(getTime, 100);
}
```

This function fills up my system memory at a rate of about 1mb per second. Why is this happening and why is the Garbage Collector collecting?

My RAM is full and the system completely unresponsive after about 30 minutes. Is this fixable?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. What is the result when the above code is absent?

Comment: Try setting the interval to 1000 and see if the memory usage is increasing 10 times slower. If not, it's something else. You can try to add `console.log(window.performance.memory)` to possibly get some more insight.

Comment: Memory stays steady w/o the above code.

Comment: Interestingly, setting timeout to 1000 seems to actually fix the memory problem. I guess I can live with only updating the time every second, but its strange nevertheless.

Comment: I take that back. After about 40 minutes the page now uses about 500 MB. This only happens in Chromium on a raspberry pi. Chrome on Windows works fine (i.e. the page uses between 50 and 60 MB memory).

Comment: i ran into the same problem, it has nothing to do with your code. running "toLocaleTimeString" seems to produce 10-20 MB of memory garbage with every run. at least in chromium this should be garbage collected every 10 seconds or so, but still.